# Item being selected automatically from spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

my issue is that whenever I add a lecture to the array list in the next activity, it calls back to this activity and updates it.  However, for some reason onItemSelected is called right away as soon as I get back to the calling activity and I'm sent to the Lecture activity (the displayLectureIntent is started right away) as soon as I get back to the calling activity without even actually selecting anything from the spinner.

Could it be that as soon as I add something to the spinner, the spinner chooses the first object as default and therefore it "selects" it?  Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_manager0);

    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    if (receivedIntent.hasExtra("lectureManagerExtra")) {
        lectureManager = (LectureManager) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lectureManagerExtra");
        update();
    } else {
        lectureManager = new LectureManager();
    }

}


public void update() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lecturespinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> lectureadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lectureManager.getLectureNames());
    lectureadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(lectureadapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HEYYY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent displayLectureIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LectureActivity.class);
            displayLectureIntent.putExtra("lectureExtra", 
                    lectureManager.returnLecture(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));
            startActivity(displayLectureIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {}
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add "select" string on lectureManager.getLectureNames() array at the top 
so that the array's size is increased by 1 
And setSelectedIndex to 0 . 
and 
modify onItemSelected method as followings

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HEYYY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent displayLectureIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LectureActivity.class);
        displayLectureIntent.putExtra("lectureExtra", 
                lectureManager.returnLecture(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));
      **if(position !=0){
        startActivity(displayLectureIntent);
  } 
   else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " select the lecture.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean by add the select string on the lectureManager.getLEctures()?

Comment: if your  list of lecture is
{"math","computer","science"} then add "select " on index 0
as below {"select","math","computer","science"}